# Add .html extension on wordpress permalink using .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, permalinks

How to add .html the end of link

normal show

```
http://med.advpedia.com/birthday-party-supplies/1st-birthday-2/lil-prince-1st-birthday-standard-party-pack
```

i want all link to be like this

```
http://med.advpedia.com/birthday-party-supplies/1st-birthday-2/lil-prince-1st-birthday-standard-party-pack.html
```

when that link changed (added .html) should be not to be 404 page not found

this is currnet .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this with Wordpress I have done it with two plugins.

-Append extensions on Pages

-Custom Post Type Permalinks(If you have custom post types)

Hope it helps!